# Ruby IO::popen and crossbow

Tags: ruby, methods, io

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000880

Looking to use this method ( I think)

To run this commandline command, from within ruby:

```
$CROSSBOW_HOME/cb_emr \
    --name "Crossbow-Ecoli" \ 
    --preprocess \ 
    --input=s3n://bgs.crossbow-01/example/e_coli/small.manifest \ 
    --output=s3n://bgs.crossbow-01/example/e_coli/output_small \ 
    --reference=s3n://
```

The above is what I enter in to the command line to run directly from console

So I'm pretty sure I've got the IO method correct... but I'm fairly lost on translating the above code into the input

Answer (score 0):

THis should do the trick:

```
command =<<END_OF_COMMAND
#{ENV["CROSSBOW_HOME"]}/cb_emr \
    --name "Crossbow-Ecoli" \ 
    --preprocess \ 
    --input=s3n://bgs.crossbow-01/example/e_coli/small.manifest \ 
    --output=s3n://bgs.crossbow-01/example/e_coli/output_small \ 
    --reference=s3n://
END_OF_COMMAND

IO.popen(command) do |handle|
  handle.each_line do |line|
     puts line
  end
end
```

I am iterating over each line of the output, because I'm guessing you may want to process it somehow.

Comment: so yeah this looks like its going to work ... whats the operation thats going on with the =<<END_OF_COMMAND  I've seen the << used to add items to the end of arrays .. but never with an equal before it

Comment: It's a multiline string. The END_OF_COMMAND specifies where the string ends.